# What is the right arrangement of these two names if we sort it

Tags: windows, vb.net, sorting, rule

I have two folders with names `CLP2_v6` and `CLP_DE0_v7`. When I tried to sort it using [Icomparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) the result is:

**Using StrCmpLogicalW(Windows):**
`CLP_DE0_v7`
`CLP2_v6`

I'm confusing right now it's because when I tried to sort that words using this [Text Line Sorter](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-sort) gave me a different answer:

**Using TextLineSorter:**
`CLP2_v6`
`CLP_DE0_v7`

What I want to display on my program is like this:

**Preferred:**
`CLP2_v6`
`CLP_DE0_v7`

Here VB.net is my code:

```
Public Class StringCompare
Implements IComparer(Of String)

Declare Unicode Function StrCmpLogicalW Lib "shlwapi.dll" _
(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Int32

Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements _
        System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare
    Return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y)
End Function
End Class

Sub Main()
Dim UsortedArray() As String = {
        "CLP_DE0_v7",
        "CLP2_v6"
      }

    Dim rc As New StringCompare()
    Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Windows Sorting:")
    Array.Sort(UsortedArray, rc)

    Console.WriteLine()
    For Each dinosaur As String In UsortedArray
        Console.WriteLine(dinosaur)
    Next
End Sub
```

What is the right arrangement if we'll try to sort these two words? Does sorting have many rules to follow? or Sorting have many standards?

Comment: Take a look at the [`StringComparison` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/8d9k4871(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx) to get an idea of the different ways `Strings` could be compared for sorting purposes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm using Unicode that's why sorting was treated in different manner. :)

Comment: Given that you're implementing `IComparer(Of String)`, the logical name for your class is `StringComparer` rather than `StringCompare`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different approaches to sorting depending on required results, context or available tools. Since you have .NET you're not limited to technology, but your own requirements.

Consider theese situations:

**Culture specific**

```
'Array sorted by English culture   
{"aa", "bb", "cc", "ch", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii"}
'Same array sorted by Czech culture   
{"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ch", "ii"}
```

And have you ever heard of ě, ê, è, é ? :)

Where do you put them? Before "e", after "e", after, "z"? That would depend on your culture and needs.

**Technology specific**

Let's say you have your ANSI string in array of bytes. Sortig by byte-value returns something different then sorting by char position in alphabet.

**User-needs specific**

Is "a" more than "A"? What in general? What in your specific need?
Is directory named "9" more than directory named "10"? Sort it as string and you'll get {"10", "9"}, open it in windows explorer and you'll see {"9", "10}. Open it in Total Commander and you'll get {"10", "9"} again for the same directory.

**Conclusion**

You should define what you really need in your specific case. And find proper or easy way how to do it. In .NET your results will depenend on `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo` or your own IComparer that you can provide to IList.Sort method or SortedList/SortedSet constructors.

**Risks**

You should be aware of different sorting under different culture info. For example creating and filling SortedList(Of String, Object) under "hu-HU" culture will cause weird exceptions in some cases after reading items under "cs-CZ" culture since the items would not be sorted as expected and binary search tree would be confused.

Comment: @Pavlinll Can I modify the `...Cultureinfo` in `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo`?

Comment: Do you really need to change the culture? If you want your `StringCompare` to compare using a specific culture, why not write that into the class? Why are you even using an API function in the first place? Why not call `String.Compare` or `String.CompareTo` and specify the culture when you make the call?

Comment: If you wanted to be able to specify the culture at run time, add a constructor to your `StringCompare` class that takes a `CultureInfo` argument and use that in the comparison.

Comment: Sure, but it makes sense only when your entire thread and everything thats running under it is related to your new culture. Just set CurrentThread.CultureInfo=New CultureInfo("cz-CZ") or anything you need. If you need this only for the sort, then providing use argument as @jmcilhinney suggested.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm using windows API because I want the file names to be sorted like windows sorting method.

Comment: So, you're using the API because you want them sorted like Windows Explorer but you want to know how to not sort them like Windows Explorer?